# How do you transition from MD5 authentication to SHA1 for NTP?

Tags: authentication, md5, sha1, sha, ntp

Does anyone know how to transition authentications on NTP? I've done copious amounts of research, none being fruitful. For example, NTP currently using MD5, how do you move over to SHA1?

Answer (score 1):

NTP if compiled along with OPENSSL libraries, then NTP uses OPENSSL libraries for cryptographic operations.
Then you can use different types of message digest algorithms supported by OPENSSL. This is a link which explains configuring ntp key file.

The key file where the keys will be present should be added to the /etc/ntp.conf file.

The keys to be used for generating the digest will be present under
/etc/ntp/keys . This path should be added to /etc/ntp.conf file to specify that this is the keys file.

The structure of the entry in the file will be

[This is an example of the keys file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klGV2.png)

You can mention the keytype as "SHA1" to use SHA1 authentication.
Further details about the length of the digest and keys can be found here:

https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/authentic.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple keys one next to the other.
SO:

- first add the new key everywhere
- delete the old key once it's added everywhere.